Can you help me to find why my ASP.NET Core 8.0 app isnt starting
When I try to run my project it errors  and all of these errors appear. I have tried everything and nothing helps.
Here is the project link on GitHub

Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Common\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Common.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data.Models\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.Models.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Common\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Common.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data.Models\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.Models.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Services.Mapping\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Services.Mapping.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Common\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Common.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data.Models\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.Models.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Services.Mapping\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Services.Mapping.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Web.ViewModels\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Web.ViewModels.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Common\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Common.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data.Models\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.Models.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Common\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Common.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data.Models\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.Models.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Services.Data\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Services.Data.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Services.Mapping\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Services.Mapping.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Web.Infrastructure\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Web.Infrastructure.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Web.ViewModels\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Web.ViewModels.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Common\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Common.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Data.Models\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Data.Models.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Services.Data\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Services.Data.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Services.Mapping\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Services.Mapping.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Web.Infrastructure\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Web.Infrastructure.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'C:\Users\PC\source\repos\JudoWebAppProject\JudoApp.Web.ViewModels\obj\Debug\net8.0\ref\JudoApp.Web.ViewModels.dll' could not be found


"Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" What does your Program.cs file look like? It's possible you're incorrectly using Top Level Statements.

FYI top level statements in a program class file also count as a main method. Are there any other warnings or errors in the visual studio build output pane?

Remove <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> on JudoApp.Data.Models.csproj and other error projects

That worked amazing thank you so much.
